# I want my code to be like Moduler. Anybody can help? VB.NET

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

```
        Dim Connectionstring As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Anbar;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sqlcommand As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim sqlconnection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim dataadapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand)
        sqlconnection.ConnectionString = Connectionstring
        sqlcommand.Connection = sqlconnection
        sqlcommand.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[User] ([name],[lastname],[username],[password]) VALUES (@name,@lastname,@username,@password)"
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtfristname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtlastname.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusernameregister.Text)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpasswordregister.Text)

        sqlconnection.Open()
        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconnection.Close()
```

My Code Already Work But I Want Be Moduler ...can any body help??

Comment: It's good that you use parameterized SQL, well done! But please, please don't store passwords as plain text.

Comment: You may need to explain a bit more what you want. Also there is a code review SE site

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can figure out that you mean by modular is to separate you user interface code from your data access code.
I created a `DataAccess` class for all your database code. You do not need an instance of the class to use `InsertUser` because it is a `Shared` method. Just use the name of the class to access it.

`Using...End Using` blocks will close and dispose you database objects. You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Pass the command text the connection to the constructor of the your command.

I changed the parameters to the `.Add` method. You will have to check your database for the correct datatype and field size.

```
Public Class DataAccess

    Private Shared ConStr As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Anbar;Integrated Security=True"

    Public Shared Sub InsertUser(fname As String, lname As String, uname As String, pword As String)
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[User] ([name],[lastname],[username],[password]) VALUES (@name,@lastname,@username,@password);", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = fname
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = lname
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = uname
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = pword
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in the form we deal with all the user interface elements. Notice that the `DataAccess` class has no idea where the parameter values are coming from (no reference to user interface text boxes and such) and the `Form` code has no idea where they are going to. It could be any database or event a text file.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataAccess.InsertUser(txtfristname.Text, txtlastname.Text, txtusernameregister.Text, txtpasswordregister.Text)
End Sub
```